# non working array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ksh

Can anyone helps with my problem with arrays in BASH?
I have this code:

```
i=1
cat test.txt | while read LINE; do
    string=$(echo $LINE | sed -e 's/\(^[^=]*\):[^=]*$/\1 /')
    log_content[$i]="$string"
    echo -e "\t $i) ${log_content[$i]}"
    i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
pattern=$(echo ${log_content[1]})   - this is zero :(
```

When I use ksh instead of bash everything works fine. When I use BASH (which aj want to use because of many others purposes), variable "pattern" desnt have any value. Even when I want to show whole content of "log_content" array, there is nothing. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your `log_content` variable is being filled inside a subshell that runs your `while` loop so the value of `log_content` variable in the outer shell never changes.

To mitigate this you should avoid creation of subshell by using input redirection instead of pipe:

```
while read LINE; do
  ...
done < test.txt
```

This should work.